# How to read "checked" files from a ListView?

Tags: list-view

I have a webpart with a ListView inside... I configured it so that i can "check" every single file... Is there any method to read the files that are checked? I must use it to apply my actions on this selected items..

Thank you very much!

Comment: pls do check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261012/accessing-sharepoint-web-services-without-authentication

Comment: Please explain "checked". Have you added a Yes/No Field to your List? If so, you'd check that field the same as any other field.

Comment: In my list there are a check list for each document.. I think it is a Sharepoint normal feature to delete multiple file / move them.. I'd like to know if there's any way to reach that "checked list" to use it for my own applications! Hope this explained my question!